# Как сделать логин к сайту api без токена?

Tags: ios, django, swift, django-rest-framework

**Создал тестового юзера:**
username: "david"
password: "framework"

```
let urlString = "http://gemcave.pythonanywhere.com/api/order"

            let email = "david"
            let password = "framework"

            let parameters = [
                "username": email,
                "password": password
            ]   

            Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString,parameters: parameters).responseJSON {response in
                let json = JSON(response.data!)
                let swiftyJsonVar = json["truckType"].string
                print(swiftyJsonVar)
            }
```

Ошибка: return `nil` - аутентификация не проходит
Я не знаю в чем именно проблема в сервере или приложении

Бэкэнд: `Django Rest Framework`

`JSON` пример:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "textDep": "Paris",
        "textDest": "Deli",
        "truckType": "Грузовик1",
        "created_date": "2015-12-22T09:42:38Z",
        "author": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "textDep": "Astana",
        "textDest": "Almata",
        "truckType": "Грузовик1",
        "created_date": "2015-12-22T09:44:13Z",
        "author": 1
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Могу предположить, что вы не активировали тестового юзера, попробуйте поднять django-admin, и оттуда уже проверить есть ли пользователь, активен ли он, есть ли у него соответствующие права, по части сервера всё сразу станет ясно.